# Map only certain properties using Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to map model to entity object, but when I map entity object that received from DB - my changes doesn't save in database.

Here is some code:

Mapping configuration:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<WalletUpdateModel, Wallet>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Name, m => m.MapFrom(d => d.Name))
    .ForMember(o => o.Currency, m => m.MapFrom(d => d.Currency));
```

Entity object:

```cs
public partial class Wallet
{
    public Wallet()
    {
        this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Owner { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Model declaration:

```cs
public class WalletUpdateModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

And some debugging info from Immediate window:

```cs
w (before mapping)
{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Wallet_E3CA830BB5384920A3E07D4B44F15D2409093A34BFCED7CA33F9EC4102445554}
    [System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Wallet_E3CA830BB5384920A3E07D4B44F15D2409093A34BFCED7CA33F9EC4102445554]: {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Wallet_E3CA830BB5384920A3E07D4B44F15D2409093A34BFCED7CA33F9EC4102445554}
    Currency: "PLN"
    Id: 2
    Name: "Cash"
    Owner: 1
    Transactions: Count = 0
w (after mapping)
{Financica.WebServices.Wallet}
    Currency: "PLN"
    Id: 2
    Name: "BZWBK"
    Owner: 0
    Transactions: Count = 0
```

Please, help me fix this problem, thank you.

Comment: Can you please confirm exactly what the issue is that you want help with? For example, is there something wrong with the mapping? If so, what is being incorrectly mapped?

Comment: I'm trying to update data entity that received from db using mapping from model, but as you can see on last code listening (from immediate window) automapper doesn't map value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you still haven't said which value is being mapped incorrectly.

As properties with the same named are automatically mapped by convention, your current mapping can changed to:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<WalletUpdateModel, Wallet>();
```

If you wish to avoid updating a destination property you can use the `UseDestinationValue` directive. If you want to apply a condition to the update you can use the `Condition` directive. If you wish to ignore the property completely, you can use the `Ignore` directive.

Finally, have you tested your mapping to ensure you haven't missed anything? For example, your mapping looks like it might have issues with `Owner` and `Transactions` as they're not defined on the `WalletUpdateModel` class. You can test your mapping with the following:

```cs
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```